# Create a dialog message that is focused on a button or textinput in react native

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I want to create a dialog message that is focused on a button or text input like the required attribute in html but I want to create it custom, is it possible in react native?

Like this one
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check [react-native-popup-menu](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu) library if it works for you or you can do it customly by create custom popup view of same style like modal with absolute position and place on bottom of the view where you want to display it so

Comment: ya I want it like this, but is this possible without using any libraries? thanks for the help though

Comment: Yes, of course, It doesn't need any library. You can create a custom view as same as you provide image above with absolute and show where you want.